# DbContext ExecuteSqlCommand - Table Valued Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, dbcontext, table-valued-parameters

I am having an issue calling a stored procedure off of my DbContext.  The stored procedure takes in a table valued parameter.

The syntax of the procedure is:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.SaveResults
  @resultID int,
  @positiveResults AS dbo.PositiveResultTypes READONLY
AS
```

I have a DataTable(`dtResults`) filled with valid values for the table type.

My calling code is:

```
var resultsParam = new SqlParameter("@positiveResults", SqlDbType.Structured);
resultsParam.Value = dtResults;
resultsParam.TypeName = "PositiveResultTypes";

db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
    "dbo.SaveResults", 
    new SqlParameter("@resultID", id),
    resultsParam);
```

This is failing with:

> Procedure or function 'SaveResults' expects parameter '@resultID',
>   which was not supplied.

The variable `id` is valid and not `null` here (`int`, value `1`).

I have tried changing the syntax to "`dbo.SaveResults @resultID @positiveResults`" in the calling code with no change in result.

Why is it not seeing this parameter?

**EDIT**

SQL Profiler shows this parameter passing correctly ...

```
declare @p3 dbo.PositiveResultTypes 
insert into @p3 values(N'1')
insert into @p3 values(N'4')
insert into @p3 values(N'6')

exec sp_executesql N'dbo.SaveResults',N'@positiveResults [PositiveResultTypes] READONLY,@resultID int',@positiveResults=@p3,@resultID=1
```

However, this syntax for the EXEC is somehow incorrect.  When I execute this against the database, I get the same result:

```
(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)
Msg 201, Level 16, State 4, Procedure SaveResults, Line 0
Procedure or function 'SaveResults' expects parameter '@resultID', which was not supplied.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
{
    // Configure the SqlCommand and SqlParameter.
    SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.SaveResults", con);
    sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    SqlParameter tvpParam = sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@positiveResults", dtResults); 

    //tell compiler that we are passing TVP
    tvpParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured; 

    sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@resultID", id));
    sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: I am trying to do this with db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand() (EF DbContext) as shown rather than raw ADO.Net, although if I have to go that way I will.

Comment: @Patrick I think you just may need to drop down to that lower level, one thing you can do however is you may be able to use `db.Database.Connection` as the connection source for your SqlCommand.

Answer (score 0):

Make resultsparameter as a parameter array, add both of your parameters to it. Then pass the parameter in ExecuteSqlCommand method.

The mentioned error is showing because two sql parameters are passed to it, while only one sql parameter can be passed to it.

Comment: I attempted to pass it this way: new object[] {resultsParam, new SqlParameter("@resultID", id)}) as the second parameter, but got the same result.  See edit, profile trace on SQL seems correct?